# 502 error for the community user's gravatar

Tags: bug

On the questions [page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions) the community user has a broken image:

[image: broken image]

The error message in Chrome is:

```
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a007be5a61f6aa8f3e85ae2fc18dd66e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 ()
```

and in Edge:

```
HTTP502: BAD GATEWAY - The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server it accessed in attempting to fulfill the request.
GET - https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a007be5a61f6aa8f3e85ae2fc18dd66e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
```

I can view the gravatar url directly and there's no error on the [community user's profile page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

I wonder if others are experiencing this?

Comment: I've experienced this on a WordCamp site in the last 24 hours, it's not a Stack Exchange specific issue

Comment: Good to know -  though I've only seen it on this site so far - yes the 502 error message comes from the Gravatar's servers. @TomJNowell

Comment: I am really glad now that I never continued work on the _Gravatar clone_ service…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an issue viewing the Community gravatar in any of the browsers I've tested it in ( IE11, FF latest, Chrome latest ). It could have been a caching issue on the site, caching issue locally, or maybe a gravatar issue that was recently resolved.

Here's [a particular question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175884/how-to-customize-the-archive-title/203884) where Community is involved in. If other people run into this issue we could escalate it.

Comment: I also experienced this on my mobile phone. But this seems to be fixed now, after seeing this broken image for about ~ 1 day. (all other gravatars were displaying correctly though, during that time). Thanks for checking.